# how to get paragraph search response from solr

Tags: search, solr, lucene

Using copyfield I copyed all the document fields in one field, after quering the result I want to show the search result in Paragraph format :

For example, I have some indexed data about solr in some documents and
if i query for

> /solr?q=copyAllFields:solr

Result should be populate as:

> [DOC-110](http://testSolr.com/solr?id=110)
>  **Solr** is an open-source search server based on
> the Lucene Java search library. News, documentation, resources, and
> download... **Solr** is a standalone enterprise search server with
> a REST-like API. You put ...
>
> [DOC-898](http://testSolr.com/solr?id=110)
>  **Solr**(pronounced "solar") is an open source enterprise search platform from the Apache... Its major features include full-text search, hit highlighting ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Solr's highlighting component](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Highlighting) for this task. This will get you an additional section in Solr's search result that contains text paragraphs the way you want it. The word that produced the hit will be surrounded within a configurable tags.

How this component can be used is rather good documented in the following sources

- [Reference Guide - Solr's highlighting component](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Highlighting)
- [Solr Wiki - HighlightingParameters](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters)
- [Using Highlighting Component in Solr](http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Using-Highlighting-Component--in-Solr)